# Using fog for rackspace cloudfiles (EU) with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, fog

i'm stuck authenticating to the **europe rackspace cloud** with **paperclip** and **fog**. i also added this line to the credentials:

```
:rackspace_auth_url => "lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com"
```

but this doesnt change anything. it still tries to authenticate with the us cloud.

has anyone got this up and running?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I have this setup working with the EU rackspace. Add the following to one of your environment files. Or configure it on a per model basis.

```rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage          => :fog,
  :fog_directory    => 'uploaded_images',
  :fog_public       => true,
  :fog_credentials  => {
    :provider           => 'Rackspace',
    :rackspace_username => 'username',
    :rackspace_api_key  => 'key',
    :rackspace_auth_url => 'lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com'
  }
}
```

One thing to note is that the urls are double encoded when using the paperclip `url` method so you will need to do something like this in your view:

```rb
user.avatar.url(:thumb, { :escape => false })
```